# What is the difference between ps.setAsciiStream() method and ps.setCLob() method in jdbc?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I have a file which is more that 32kb (it contains 34000 characters including tabs and spaces). When I try to insert it in an Oracle 11g database below scenario occurs.

1. When I use `preparedStatment.setAsciiStream(1, inputStream, inputStream.avalaible())`, the insert statement which I execute from JDBC fails with an Arrayindexoutofboundexception(4096).
2. When I use `preparedstatement.setCLOB(1, newInputStreamReader(inputstream))`, it works.

What is the difference between this 2 approaches?

What are the actual restrictions on CLOB datatype?

Comment: Don't use `inputStream.available()`. It doesn't give you the number of bytes in the file, only the number of bytes available in the buffer.

Comment: Consider trying `setAsciiStream(int, InputStream)`, or pass the actual length of the file to the `setAsciiStream(int, InputStream, int)` method. `InputStream.available()` does not usually return the total length, but can also return 0 or the length of data currently buffered.